# How to navigate to initial view controller from any view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I want to navigate to the initial view from almost any View Controller in my storyboard. I don't want to create a segue manually for every view to the initial view. Is there a nice and handy way to do this in one line, or maybe a method that my other VC could inherit?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this (in my opinion) would be using a UINavigation Controller.

Make the UINavigation Controller the root view controller of your storyboard, then connect it to your "actual" root view controller.

Then, from any view controller that has been pushed with the navigation controller, you can do:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // or NO
```

Comment: How do you make something the root view of the entire storyboard?

Comment: On one of your view controllers in your storyboard there is a right facing arrow attached to the left side of the VC.  It's probably attached to the very first VC that you added to your storyboard.  It designates the root view controller.  Drag it to another VC to change it.

Comment: Altough this seems like a pretty good idea, somehow my screen just turns up black. Could this be because I have a UINavigationController as root (initial) view?

Comment: It should pop back to whatever is the first thing connected to the UINavigationController. Sorry for the late response by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a strong reference to the initial/root view controller you want in the AppDelegate, and then setup a method within it that you call from anywhere to switch the current view controller to your initial controller.

You would do something like this in the AppDelegate.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyInitialViewController *initialViewController
- (void)switchToInitialViewController;
```

In the AppDelegate.m you can do:

```
- (void)switchToInitialViewController
{
    self.window.rootViewCotroller = self.initialViewController;
}
```

And then you can do this from any method:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate switchToInitialViewController];
```

And that, hopefully, helps. :)

Comment: Hey, that looks really clever! Will try that right now :)

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? With some tweaks and perhaps a proper setup, that idea in general can work :)

Comment: If the key window is still the window that appDelegate is holding on to then its likely already the case that self.window.rootViewController is the same controller you stashed a reference to.  This also doesn't take into account container controllers like UINavigationController or UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifer isEqualToString:@"identifier"]) {
      // Put your code here....
    }
}
```

Every ViewController have this kind of method inside and you can move to other controller or your intial Controller. and if you're using NavigationController then you can go for 
@Eric answer.